# outbound messages limit

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

I would like to mass update leads which have workflow rules that update records in another sytem.

Is there outbound messsages limit in SFDC? As I'm using the Unlimited Edition, I understand I have unlimited API requrests but wondering if SOAP API migh impact the number of outbound messages sent.

Answer (score 3):

The best source for this is the [Salesforce Limits cheat sheet](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf)

From what I am aware there isn't a limit on the number of outbound messages sent.

Also note that despite being on "Unlimited Edition" you are limited in the number of API calls that you can make, this limit is 5,000 per user licence within any 24 hour period. (Unless you have had this amended by arrangment with Salesforce)

Comment: Thanks! how do I calculate the number of records that go into  a single call? e.g. if I upload 5,000 records at once in Salesforce, does it count as one call or as 5,000 calls?

Comment: It depends on how you go about doing the upload. From what you've said, I believe that you have a custom application that is making the calls to Salesforce. Each HTTP request is one API call. That's regardless of whether the request has one record in it, or 5,000. Of course if you try and fit too many records into a single custom request you may hit other limits (for the size of message or for a long running query). In general I always aim to send batches of records, and I often go for 200 at a time to match the Apex trigger batch size.

Comment: thanks for the info! I just found the API Limits Quick Reference and says that "Limits are enforced against the aggregate of all API calls made by the organization in a 24 hour period; limits are not on a per-user basis."

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear on that, the limit is at the org level but it is a limit, not unlimited.

Comment: My developer edition has an API limit of 5,000 calls, but my Config Sandbox has a limit of 3,000,000 calls, and Production has a limit of 5,000,000. Why those numbers are different? It depends on the Edition or on the number of users?

Comment: Developer edition has a limit of 5,000. For an Unlimited Edition production org the limit is number of users x 5,000. For example we have 210 users and our api limit is 1,050,000 per 24 hours. In our Sandbox the limit is the same (1,050,000). I'm not sure why your Config sandbox is different from Production. Normally it has the limit which was in place when the sandbox was last refreshed.

Comment: make senses, we have more than 600 users and the sandbox might need to be refreshed..

Comment: Outbound messages are batched and can contain up to 100 objects in a payload.

Comment: WHOA! FYI - the 5000 API calls per user is for calls INBOUND to salesforce. There is no limit to OUTBOUND calls/day/user. The only outbound limit is the # of long running (2 minute) API calls - calls that hang due to non-salesforce system response time.